# Default value for Pagination in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I'm wondering if theres a way that you can set a default value for the pagination in Codeigniter.
For example, when you enter "page 2", it will send out a post data, but If i enter "page 1", then it wont send out any post data. So, can I change this? So it sends out a default value for the first page?

Any respons is appreciated.

Comment: You need to elaborate your issue.

Comment: provide some source code that what are you trying

Comment: if youre using the pagination library, youre probably using the uri helper to pull in the page number.  Which means you can set a variable to the pages uri segment, and if its empty set it to 0 or something......

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can change default option for pagination for your entire project. No need to work in each controller.
`site/system/libraries/Pagination.php` look here line 29-62 are all default option you may change from here.

Warning: any upgrade for future version will affect it